# Team City Projects and User Accounts Migration to Test Environment

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0

We have a production team city and we would like to migrate the user accounts and project to our team city test server. Is there an easy way to do this? Should i move some xml files from the TeamCityData directory?

Any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the easiest method to carry out something like this is through the use of the Backup and restore functionality of team-city.

take a full backup of your teamcity server (instructions can be found here: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Creating+Backup+from+TeamCity+Web+UI)

then restore this backup onto your test environment.

this should give you what you need. alternative methods for backing up are detailed here:
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/TeamCity+Data+Backup